# Having trouble saving changes in Dataset to SQL LocalDB

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, state, localdb

My problem is that I can connect to database and in my application everything works great and when I update a field, the changes are shown in the application but when I close and reopen the application no changes where saved, my codes are like below.

ps: my database is inside my application.

```
var res = db.bibleContext.Where(x => x.Book == bookF && x.Chapter == chapterF && x.Verse == verseF).FirstOrDefault();
            res.favoriteverse = i;
            db.Entry(res).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
```

and my connection string is:

```
<add name="Dholybible" connectionString="Data Source=(Localdb)\mssqllocaldb;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\HollyBible.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: are you checking if the Model state dictionary is in a Valid state before trying to save the changes?

Comment: Maybe you're running an initializer that deletes and recreates the database each time you start the app?

Comment: no, all records in database is there

Comment: Is it possible that you copy the local DB to the execution folder of your app? In this case it would be overwritten when the app starts. Try copy the mdf file to your documents folder and access it there. Change the connection string accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Solution. Before save changes, attache the local change sets to db...

```
var res = db.bibleContext.Where(x => x.Book == bookF && x.Chapter == chapterF && x.Verse == verseF).FirstOrDefault();
        res.favoriteverse = i;
        db.bibleContext.Attach(res);
        db.Entry(res).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
```